# How to clear array using callback in async nodejs once processing is done?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a search functionality based on user date ranges. Sometimes I see results from server, in some cases it returns empty response array `matches`.

How can we make sure `async.eachSeries()` is done and send results to client and clear array for next search? I tried to apply `setTimeout` but that did not resolve the problem.

search.js

```
var matches;
var results = [];


// loop through each file
async.eachSeries(filesData.logFiles, function(logfile, done) {
    // read file
    readStream = fs.createReadStream('./logs/' + filesData.searchEnv + '/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8')
    readStream.pipe(split())
        .on('data', function(line) {
            if (typeof searchStr === 'string') {
                multipleStrFlag = false;
                if (messageDateInfo - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - messageDateInfo > 0) {
                    results.push({
                        filename: logfile.filename,
                        value: line
                    });

                }
            } else {
                multipleStrFlag = true;
                if (messageDateInfo - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - messageDateInfo > 0) {
                    results.push({
                        filename: logfile.filename,
                        value: line
                    });

                }

            };
        });
    done();
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    }
});

readStream.on('end', function() {
    if (multipleStrFlag) {
        var matchingCondition = function matchingCondition(_ref) {
            var itemB = _ref.itemB,
                itemA = _ref.itemA;
            return itemB.value.includes(itemA);
        };
        // filter all items from B that satisfy a matching condition with at least one item from A
        matches = results.filter(function(itemB) {
            return searchStr.every(function(itemA) {
                return matchingCondition({
                    itemB: itemB,
                    itemA: itemA
                });
            });
        });
    } else {
        matches = results;
    }
    setTimeout(function,(){
    callback(matches);
    matches = [];
    results = [];
   },1000);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

async provides the following syntax.

```
eachSeries(coll, iteratee, callback)
```

Wherein the callback is called only when all iteratee functions are finished.

Using this, you could update the  callback function to

```
function (err){
  if(err) {//handle err}
  results = []
}
```

Which should clear the results array post eachSeries